# How to disable TYPO3 backend logout screen

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I want to disable the logout feature. I want stay logged in lifetime.
I tried to :

```
set [FE][lifetime] = 86400 (at least one day)
set [FE][permalogin] = 2
set [BE][lockIP]=0
set [BE][sessionTimeout] = 3600
```

But the system quicks me out in few min.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use below typoscript.

```
['BE']['sessionTimout'] to 3600*24*7
```